# double sum simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, symbolic-computation

I'm looking for a simplification to the following expression

$$
\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{l=0}^m \binom{m}{j} \binom{m}{l} h(j+l)
$$ 
where $h$ is a given function.

I looked for a formula of the product of binomial coefficients but I couldn't find it also I tried to simplify it using maple but in vain ! is it complicated this much ?! because it looks like a familiar formula. Any hint or help will be so appreciated :) thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=0}^{m}\sum_{l=0}^{m}\binom{m}{j}\binom{m}{l}h(j+l) = \sum_{k=0}^{2m}h(k)\sum_{j+l=k}\binom{m}{j}\binom{m}{l} = \sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{k}h(k)$$
by [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: is it $h(j+m)$ on the left term or $h(j+l)$ ?

Comment: @houda: right, fixed.